# How to sort Arrays of Object using aggregation in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

How can I sort `dueDate` using aggregate?

```
todos: [
    {
        task: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: 'Please Enter your Task',
        },
        dueDate: Date,
        dueTime: String,
    },
],
```

I tried these things but it didn't work.

```
db.server.aggregate(
    { $unwind: '$todos' },
    { $sort: { 'todos.dueDate': -1 } },
    { $group: { _id: '$_id', todos: { $push: '$todos' } } },
    { $project: { 'todos.dueDate': '$dueDate' } }
);
```

And

```
db.server.aggregate(
    { $unwind: '$todos' },
    { $sort: { 'todos.dueDate': -1 } },
    { $group: { "_id": "$_id", todos: { $push: '$todos' } } },
);
```

I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong in the aggregation.

**Example:-**

**Sample Input**

```
{
  _id: 603ba275cc571e2404e0dd1b,
  task: 'task 1',
  dueDate: 2021-02-27T18:30:00.000Z,
  dueTime: ''
},{
  _id: 603ba285cc571e2404e0dd1c,
  task: 'task 2',
  dueDate: 2021-03-30T18:30:00.000Z,
  dueTime: '07:32 PM'
},{
  _id: 603ba290cc571e2404e0dd1d,
  task: 'task 3',
  dueDate: 2021-03-08T18:30:00.000Z,
  dueTime: '07:32 PM'
},{
  _id: 603ba3a7fea412537c295056,
  task: 'task4',
  dueDate: 2021-03-01T18:30:00.000Z,
  dueTime: '07:37 PM'
}
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
  _id: 603ba275cc571e2404e0dd1b,
  task: 'task 1',
  dueDate: 2021-02-27T18:30:00.000Z,
  dueTime: ''
},{
  _id: 603ba3a7fea412537c295056,
  task: 'task4',
  dueDate: 2021-03-01T18:30:00.000Z,
  dueTime: '07:37 PM'
},{
  _id: 603ba290cc571e2404e0dd1d,
  task: 'task 3',
  dueDate: 2021-03-08T18:30:00.000Z,
  dueTime: '07:32 PM'
},{
  _id: 603ba285cc571e2404e0dd1c,
  task: 'task 2',
  dueDate: 2021-03-30T18:30:00.000Z,
  dueTime: '07:32 PM'
}
```

Comment: So you don't actually want to group by the date?

Comment: no, i just want it to return the sorted ```dueDate```

Comment: the dates are store in this format ```Tue Mar 09 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to `group` the tasks elements into separate groups by their `dueDate` and then sort those groups, here's what you can do:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$todos"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$todos.dueDate",
      todos: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "_id": -1
    }
  },
  
])
```

Here's a working example on mongoplayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/n3cfrLvR2WM

---

After OP edited the question and clarified what the expceted result is, this can be simplified to:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$todos"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "todos.dueDate": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Mongoplayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/YVCAiXrJJPv

Comment: See edit .. note that you should always include expected results to your question to make it easier to help you ..

Comment: I dont know why but it is still now working

Comment: Well, it works as expected on the mongoplayground, right? Or is this not what you want?

Comment: Ya, it was working on the mongoplayground but it is not working in my project :(

Comment: Note that you need to use `"todos.dueDate": 1` if you want the record to be sorted ascending. Is that the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229322/discussion-between-arpit-falcon-and-eol).